# Ubuntu 15.10 changed gpg

Tags: encryption, thunderbird, evolution, gnupg, 15.10

I just updated to Ubuntu 15.10 and now I can't do pgp encryptions for my E-mails with the Thunderbird add-on, enigmail. I also tried to encrypt using the Evolution email client, but that doesn't work either. I can still encrypt things from command line, but the password prompt looks different than it did in 15.04, so I'm guessing the problem that 15.10 uses a different version of gpg, and it isn't compatible with enigmail for some reason.

So could someone help me get Thunderbird or Evolution to encrypt and sign my E-mails in Ubuntu 15.10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. It had to do with "pinentry" not being installed, which means you were not getting prompted to enter your pgp key passphrase.

There are various versions.

pinentry-tty 0.9.5-4
  pinentry-qt4 0.9.5-4
  pinentry-gtk2 0.9.5-4
  pinentry-curses 0.9.5-4
  pinentry-gnome3 0.9.5-4

I installed

```
sudo apt-get install pinentry-gtk2
```

Then RESTART your session, and it should work.

[EDIT]

You might also need to install gpg2

```
sudo apt-get install gnup2g
```

Then in thunderbird -> Enigmail -> Preferences. Make sure that it detects:

GnuPGP was found in /usr/bin/gpg2

Otherwise override with /usr/bin/gpg2

Comment: Thanks; this worked for me! I didn't have to install gnup2g; just installing pinentry was enough.

Comment: It should read `sudo apt-get install gnupg2` instead.

Answer (score 0):

As someone said installing gnupg2g will get it working.

But after installing it, I needed to run a `gpg2 -version` to get it to write a config file in /home directory for it to work.

However the current version of pinentry does not support pasting a password from a password manager, so you really need to know the password or your in trouble.

One work around I found with Keepass2, is to set it to autotype with the window labelled as pinentry, and the the parameters set to

```
{PASSWORD}{ENTER}
```

It is a little fiddly, as the pinentry enter screen is on top of the screen and cannot be moved or minimised.

This seems to be a "Feature" of gpg2, and I cannot seem to find a better solution.

I doubt I will remember a 64 character gpg key :-) so stuck with this until I figure something better out